# How to change Fireloop default port 4200

Tags: fireloop

When i start the webapp and server with "fireloop serve" command fireloop is starting the webapp in 4200 port. After lot of googling i couldn't find any solution.

Could you guys please help me to find this answer.

Comment: try with: `fireloop serve --port {another port}` ie `fireloop serve --port 11111`

Answer (score 1):

**There are two ways to change the fireloops port:**

**1. Change the port in the "config.json"**
The config.json is located in your "server" directory.

```
server
|-- boot
|-- component-config.json
|-- component-config.json
|-- config.json
|-- datasources.json
|-- middleware.development.json
|-- middleware.json<br>
|-- model-config.json
`-- server.js
```

Now you can change the "port":

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 3000,
  "url": "http//localhost:3000/",
  "remoting": {
    "context": false,
    "rest": {
      "handleErrors": false,
      "normalizeHttpPath": false,
      "xml": false
    },
    "json": {
      "strict": false,
      "limit": "500mb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
      "extended": true,
      "limit": "500mb"
    },
    "cors": false
  }
}
```

Restart your fireloop server and the command line shows your new port:

```
Web server listening at: http//localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http//localhost:3000/explorer
```

---

**2. The temporary way**


As mentioned by [eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc)  before, you can change the fireloop port temporary by adding the port parameter:

> try with: fireloop serve --port {another port} ie fireloop serve
>   --port 11111